# Entity Framework not updating record

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have this method in the ParametersController class:

```
        public string SaveParameter(int id, string param, string val)
    {
        ProjectConfigurations config = new ProjectConfigurations();
        ProjectConfigurationsDAO dao = new ProjectConfigurationsDAO();

        config = dao.GetProjectConfigurationsByProjectAndParameter(id, param);
        
        config.Value = val;

        dao.Edit(config);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = true, data = config });
        //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);
    }
```

In my BaseDao class, I have this:

```
        public void Edit(T entity)
    {
        using (context = new Context())
        {
            context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The record is not updated. I'm new to EF, what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never try to create any generic repository since they are uselless. Try this

```
    public string SaveParameter(int id, string param, string val)
    {
        using (context = new Context())
        {
         var existedConfig=conext.Set<Config>.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id==id);
         existedConfig.Value=val;
          context.Entry<Config>(existedConfig).State = EntityState.Modified;
         context.SaveChanges();
         return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = true, data = config });
        }
```

Comment: I had to attach the config object before setting its state as modified, but otherwise it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help! =D